# First row of GridView table is missing data

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

When I call gvTags.DataSource = GetTags() and gvTags.DataBind() it shows that all the rows and columns have the appropriate data.

When the OnRowDataBound function is hit, the last columns in my first table row have no data (null values).

The only difference between this table and the others I've created is that I am showing/hiding columns based on a user selection higher in the page.  But - the showing/hiding is done within the OnRowDataBound function, where the data is already missing.  I have *no* idea what's going on, or where to even start for looking further.

**UPDATE:** It looks like the problem is caused by the last three lines of the RowDataBound function.  When I remove those three rows, the data displays as it should.  So - I need a way to show/hide those three columns based on if a user selects a checkbox elsewhere on the page (Include Removed Entries).  If the checkbox *is* selected, the RemovedBy and RemovedDate columns are visible.  If it is *not* selected, those hide but the Description column is visible.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTags" CssClass="table table-striped" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowSorting="false" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="gvTags_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="TagID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" OnClick="btnRemove_Click">
                    Remove
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReapply" runat="server" OnClick="btnReapply_Click">
                    Re-Apply
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TagID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InstalledBy" HeaderText="Installed By" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InstalledDate" HeaderText="Date Installed" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RemovedBy" HeaderText="Removed By" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RemovedDate" HeaderText="Date Removed" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsRemoved" Visible="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Page.IsPostBack) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    gvTags.DataSource = GetTags()
    gvTags.DataBind()

    'NOTE - Here, DataSource has complete data (all rows & columns that should have data, do have data)

    If (gvTags.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        gvTags.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub gvTags_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If (Not e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    e.Row.FindControl("btnRemove").Visible = Not Boolean.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsRemoved").ToString)
    e.Row.FindControl("btnReapply").Visible = Boolean.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsRemoved").ToString)

    'NOTE - Here, gvTags.Columns(columnIndex) is null for each of the below three columns (RemovedBy, RemovedDate, and Description)

    gvTags.Columns(removedByColumnIndex).Visible = checkbox.Checked
    gvTags.Columns(removedDateColumnIndex).Visible = checkbox.Checked
    gvTags.Columns(descriptionColumnIndex).Visible = (Not checkbox.Checked)
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the last 3 lines of your RowDataBound handler. Each column needs to be shown/hidden while processing every record? If so, the final result will depend only on the last data row. You could do that just after binding you data, I think, since the check box is not in the grid (if I am not mistaken). As for your main question, if these 3 lines are not there, do you see all your data?

Comment: The InstalledBy and InstalledDate rows will show regardless.  The user has the option (with a checkbox higher up on the page - not in the gridview, correct) to show/hide records that have been removed.  If removed records are not shown, then Removed columns are hidden.  Description is shown when Removed columns are hidden because I now have the space to include it, and the client wants it included if possible.

Comment: I posted an answer, assuming that the showing/hiding of the columns depends only on the CheckBox (as shown in your code). Your comment seems to suggest something different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion: if you columns are to be shown/hidden depending on a CheckBox outside of the grid, you could do this in the markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ... />
```

And process the event in code-behind:

```
Private Sub chkBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBox.CheckedChanged
    gvTags.Columns(removedByColumnIndex).Visible = chkBox.Checked
    gvTags.Columns(removedDateColumnIndex).Visible = chkBox.Checked
    gvTags.Columns(descriptionColumnIndex).Visible = (Not chkBox.Checked)
    gvTags.DataSource = GetTags()
    gvTags.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this.  The columns show/hide properly, but now all of the 3 optional columns have no data in them (instead of just the first row).

And you are correct - if these columns are shown/hidden is only dependent on that checkbox.

Comment: You bind your data on each postback. Is is bound after showing/hiding the columns? Make sure it is bound after. That may help. I edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Fixed, thank you!  Binding *after* showing/hiding the columns fixed it.